# How do Android reverse engineering tools extract packages/ package hierarchy present in Android apps?

Tags: mobile, android, reverse-engineering, appsec

I have been involved in disassembling Android apps using [baksmali](https://code.google.com/p/smali/) and dexpler. Whenever I disassemble an app, I find the packages and package hierarchy (that would have been available in development scenario) intact. For instance, when I disassemble a task manager app (MD5: 3377f8527479ab4e72bf9fa5eec62abe), I get the package hierarchy as shown in the figure below.[image].

In this context, I have the following questions,

1. Will this hierarchy of Java packages be preserved and retained while building apps. When we develop apps, of course, we use many packages and we put them in a hierarchy while we build the app. But, all the code written by developers will be converted into a single classes.dex file. Will the packages and package hierarchy information be retained in this classes.dex file or any other part of the apk file (like META-INF)?
2. If this information is not available from .dex, where does this come from? How does every disassembling/ decompiling tool manages to extract this package hierarchy?
3. Where to find documentation/ literature relevant to packages and package hierarchy in the app building process? I tried skimming thro' Android documentation in vain.

Comment: This is off topic here - so I'll migrate over to android.se for you